# Windows 10 – change start power options labels

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, power, rename

I would like to change the title of power options in **start menu**.

I did try some [experiments](http://www.heaventools.com/download-resource-editor.htm) with some *.dll.mui* files (*ShutdownUX.dll.mui* and *powrprof.dll.mui* for instance) and [registry keys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/power-settings/power-button-and-lid-settings) but the strings are saved apparantly somewhere else.

Does anybody know exact way in Windows 10?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and most flexible way to do so is with a third-party tool, such as [*Open Shell Menu*](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu) or the older [*Classic Start Menu*](http://www.classicshell.net/), which still works in Windows 10 v. 1809. Using a third-party tool also averts Windows Update from replacing your carefully-modified Windows files.

To give you some idea of its flexibility, see all the choices I've enabled, below. The text and icons of the menu items can be configured as you would.

またね

[image: Shutdown options]

Comment: +1 for pointing out the classic shell replacement which I wasn't aware of :)

Comment: I use full start menu and I am happy with it this time. Sorry.